# Why number of tag filters in review queue is limited to three?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

Having tag filters improve productivity of reviewers but I think the number of tags that a reviewer is interested in is usually more than three.

I should add that the tag filter is an OR filter (not an AND filter)

Comment: More than three at a time? That's already a very narrow filter. Can you provide an example set of tags that you're trying to use?

Comment: I expect the reasons for this to be performance related

Comment: @BilltheLizard I meant something like an 'or' filter or like favorite tags. To view those posts that are related to our area of expertise.

Comment: Rene is correct; tag filtering is slow as hell. We originally wanted to use folks' favorite/ignored tags for this, but... No dice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to wait a bit but [Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9) confirmed my suspicion:

> tag filtering is slow as hell. We originally wanted to use folks' favorite/ignored tags for this, but... No dice.

It might not be to obvious from the queues with a limited amount of questions in it but in the Close Vote Queue being filtered leads to either [longer load times for questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221614/loading-next-item-from-the-close-vote-queue-takes-longer-and-longer) or even [next items that never get loaded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244335/loading-next-item-from-the-close-vote-queue-ends-in-an-error).

Being able to filter the review tasks in different ways has a long history and [lot of proposals](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=queue+filtering). Yours is blocked by technical limits within the current system.