# Why is maximum number of tags on a question set to 5?

Tags: discussion, tags

Why is there a limit of five (5) tags for a posted question?

**Edit:** *I would like to point out that this question is not a feature request to extend the limit of 5 tags. It is rather a question as to the rationale as to why a limit of 5 tags was chosen at some time.*

There have been a few times when I have wanted to add an additional tag to a question that already has five (5) tags associated with it. Since there are already five tags, the maximum number of tags, I either have to remove a tag in order to add a tag or just forgo the tag edit.

Most of the time when faced with this, I decide to forgo the tag edit, deciding that the existing tags are sufficient and the new tag I would like to add does not provide any better of a categorization than the existing tags.

However there have been a few times when I really would have liked the option to add a sixth tag rather than choosing an existing tag to remove.

I'm curious why the maximum of 5 tags was chosen. It is a kind of nice round number between 1 (clearly too few) and 10 (clearly too many) but why not say 7 (as in span of control, 7 plus or minus 2)?

I did find this post, [Why number of tag filters in review queue is limited to three?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310068/why-number-of-tag-filters-in-review-queue-is-limited-to-three), which has an answer indicating that the limit is due to the impact of tag filters on load time. So perhaps the idea was to limit to 3 plus or minus two and 3 + 2 is 5?

Comment: Cross-site dupe of [Why is there a limit to the number of tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/34732)

Comment: *The truth is, no matter how many tags were allowed, there are outlier questions that the author thinks needs just one more tag.*

Comment: Not that I don't believe you, but I would very much like to see an example where more than five tags are relevant - because I just can't imagine what kind of question that would be. One or two seems to be plenty for most questions, maybe three tags if it is a question about interoperability between technologies. But more than that is usually just overzealousness.

Comment: 5, is more than enough. Most of the time, less than that is enough too. Tags should be about what the question is about, and that is often pretty succinct. Allowing users to add more tags will just promote Tag Spam to be worse than it already is. I am sure that programmers get fed of of questions with their tag being used when it's about a SQL problem, and the language the OP is using for their application is their's (but has nothing with the problem), just like i find it annoying to see questions about c# get tagged with [tag:sql-server] because that's there the data is stored.

Comment: It is not impossible to have [6 tags](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1376469#graph) and that is caused by a (former) CM : https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44162982/timeline

Comment: @Gimby It has been rare and usually when I was looking for a particular and more less used tag for a problem and found a post or two that did not have the tag I was looking for but also already had 5 tags. I don't have a specific example as this came to mind from a different perspective, editing a wiki page.

Comment: the absolute maximum of all tagnames and the enclosing < and >  needs to stay under 250 chars. That rules out 7 tags as tagnames can be 35 chars and that will no longer fit in the Posts.Tags field (a denormalized string representation of all the tags on the question). Making the field larger is probably too much of a change for little gain.

Comment: And yes, we do have tagnames that are 35 chars long: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1376497

Comment: @Larnu I agree that a tag should be what the question is about. A tag also provides a search criteria, much like a hashtag. And this question has nothing to do with tag spamming. However I've had a case such as wanting to add a particular IoT device when retagging a question about that device and there were already 5 tags. The training issue of people incorrectly using tags has nothing to do with this question. People can incorrectly use tag with a smaller tag limit.

Comment: @rene 5 time 35 is 175 so adding two more would still be under the 250 character limit (7 * 35 = 245).

Comment: No, each tag is enclosed between < and > so you need 14 ( 7 * 2 = 14) extra characters on top of the 245.

Comment: @rene Aha. Thank you. I think my next question should be a feature request to allow hashtags in questions to be searchable. Maybe if I delete it fast enough when the downvotes start rolling in and before someone posts and answer I can get the Peer Pressure badge.

Comment: For [20,660](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1376499) questions there have been 2 or more tag edits where the number of tags was 5 (or more) which could indicate an attempt was made to retag to something better. That query is terribly slow so I won't add a check now to see if subsequent tag edits actually changed the tags. I expect that number to be lower.

Comment: @rene thank you for running the query. Combining your results with those of Martijn Pieters' query it appears that out of approximately 270,000 posts with a count of 5 tags, 20,600 of those posts had some type of edit where someone attempted to edit the tags?

Comment: edited multiple times, yes. That was the idea as your concern seemed to be *adding an extra tag when already 5 tags are used*.

Answer (score 26):

There is no need for more tags. As [Robert Cartiano (former Community Manager) has stated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34732/why-is-there-a-limit-to-the-number-of-tags):

> no matter how many tags were allowed, there are outlier questions that the author thinks needs just one more tag.

Almost invariably, if you think a post needs more than 5 tags, *the post is too broad*. The fact that there is a limit to the number of tags helps keep posts within a reasonable scope.

When you [plot the number of tags per post](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1376472/number-of-tags-per-post#graph), you'll find a curve that looks a lot like a normal distribution:

[image: Graph plotting the number of questions with 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 or even 6 tags]

Yes, there are posts with 6 tags. In the past, when tags had to be replaced by a combination of tags Community Managers have temporarily overridden the tag count limit to avoid having to manually edit thousands of posts. Whenever one such post is edited, the editor has to adjust the number of tags to 5 or fewer.

However, the *vast majority of questions* (86.8%) use *fewer* than 5 tags per post.

Comment: This is interesting information and I appreciate it. However it doesn't explain why the magical number of 5 was arrived at. I come across questions with one or two tags that clearly need another tag due to the subject matter. How many people use one or two common tags that immediately come to mind and don't bother to come up with an additional one or two that help to narrow down the field and reach to specific subject matter experts watching those additional tags?

Comment: @RichardChambers: Why is there a need for a more precise definition? You could [listen to the 2008 podcast series](https://stackoverflow.blog/2008/04/17/podcast-1/) to see if Joel and Jeff have more to say on the subject, but truth be told, "5" is a natural number to start with (there never was a different limit, from the very start), and it has worked well for 12 years now.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I had a bit of trouble until I found this complete list at https://stackoverflow.blog/podcast/  I dislike podcasts as not being searchable. Most of these seem to be a couple people chatting around the fire, rambling along about various topics and I don't see any value in to going through some 300 podcasts before discovering that no one bothered to discuss the rationale behind the magic number 5. Isn't there a comment in the source code somewhere like "Max of 5 tags. That should be plenty. Nobody will use more than 3 anyway?"

Comment: @RichardChambers: there are [transcripts](https://stackoverflow.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W4); there is some discussion on tagging in [episode 9](https://stackoverflow.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W7782) & [episode 18](https://stackoverflow.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W24213); I scanned through the first 30 transcripts with a quick search ('tags' is not a great keyword when Jeff also talks about HTML tags). I don't see any mention of a specific lmit, however.

Comment: @RichardChambers: The source code of Stack Overflow is not public. Jeff Atwood would know if there was such a comment but has not seen to mention it when this subject first came up in [August 2009](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13912/5-tags-is-too-few) (less than a year after the site started). Note that in the early days there was no Meta site, and the Uservoice site Meta replaced was not archived, so any discussion there is lost.

Comment: There is an interesting discussion about the concept of tags in  [episode 9](https://stackoverflow.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W7782)  at `[10:10]` as well as [episode 18](https://stackoverflow.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W24213) at `[12:44]`. Thank you for sharing these. Its interesting to read the discussion back and forth as they are hammering out the shape of Stack Overflow. There's a bit about a filter limit and they discuss a limit of top 3 or 4 tags. "So if you look at your profile, for example, my profile.  If I look at the number of tags, I have 48 StackOverflow tags, ha ha ha."

Comment: I thought this meta posting interesting, [Could we make tags imply other tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2781/could-we-make-tags-imply-other-tags) however one answer references podcast 45 which has an incomplete transcript and I can't find out how to listen to it. https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/03/12/podcast-45/ and looking further it appears other older episodes don't have an audio track available.

Comment: "*There is no need for more tags.*" I think a more accurate statement is "there is no agreed upon ideal number of tags". Many people *do* see a need for more tags... so there *is* a need for more tags, at least for them/their questions.

Comment: It's not at all rare for focused questions (e.g. about how GCC compiles something for x86-64 and whether that's efficient or not) to merit tags like `[c] [assembly] [x86-64] [gcc]`, leaving room for only one other tag.  (Which might be [sse], [avx], [simd], [performance], [micro-optimization], [inline-assembly], [abi], or something else.  But we don't have room to pick more than 1.  Your bold assertion that any question needing more tags is too broad doesn't match my experience at all.

Comment: You could argue that maybe x86-64 should be x86-64-assembly for example, avoiding the separate [assembly] tag, but traditionally that's not how we do it.  And with compilers and assembly inherently being an intersection of multiple things, that's always going to use up multiple tag slots on such questions.